# response to ajax with file doesn't work

Tags: ajax, laravel, laravel-4, response

I use jquery jtable send ajax to get excel file from server but Response::download doesn't work

```
  $writer = (new WriterFactory())->createWriter(new  Excel5(public_path().'/file/myExport.xls'));
  $phpExcel = $writer->convert($workbook);
  $writer->write($phpExcel);

 Response::download(public_path().'\file\myExport.xls');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Javascript cannot access file system, you cannot use ajax to download files. Try using an iframe pointing to the file to download it.

```
<iframe id="downloadFrame" style="display:none"/>
```

When you need to download, use this script:

```
var iframe = document.getElementById("downloadFrame");
iframe.src = "yourpathtofile";
```

If you use jQuery, you can try:

```
$("#downloadFrame").attr("src","yourpathtofile");
```

Another solution is using `window.open`

```
window.open("pathtoyourfle");
```