# how to RECEIVE downloadable file from server in AngularJS?

Tags: angularjs, download

I am sending a downloadable file from backend to AngularJS. Whenever a GET request (with some data as parameters) is made to the "/report" url, the server sends a file that I want to receive in AngularJS. Ideally, a browser should prompt user for saving/opening a file that server sends. So far I have done this:

```
$scope.getReport = function () {

    console.log("getReport");

    var report_url = '/report';
    var some_data = "asdf";


    $http({method:'GET', url:report_url, data=some_data})
    .success(function(data) {

    });
};
```

Now I am unable to figure out how to get the file that server sent me.

Comment: take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18709783/response-to-ajax-with-file-doesnt-work/18710035#18710035

Answer (score 1):

I created this fiddle for you http://jsfiddle.net/xMdQV/

Instead of making a get request and waiting for the server to return a file that you want to download
you could replace `someData with your some_data`
Tested on Chrome, Firefox and IE9.